# Find Native SQL Query from TypedQuery

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I need to know what query is being executed on the database so I can check if I can improve it.

The following code is used to create a query:

```
TypedQuery<OrderItem> orderItemTypedQuery = typedQuery.setParameter(OrderItemCriteria.CUSTOMER_ID_PARAM, criteria.getCustomerId());

String sqlQuery=orderItemTypedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
```

The following query is shown:

```
select generatedAlias0 from OrderItem as generatedAlias0 left join generatedAlias0.order as generatedAlias1 where ( generatedAlias0.status in (:param0) ) and ( generatedAlias0.hidden=:param1 ) and ( generatedAlias0.customer.id=:param2 ) and ( generatedAlias0.linkedOrderItem is null ) order by generatedAlias1.id desc, generatedAlias0.id desc
```

The query above isn't native (parameteres aren't set), I'm trying to find what is being executed on the database so that I can check if the query is slow and needs to be optimised.

Thanks

Comment: For the latest version of Hibernate, you need to change the class to org.hibernate.query.Query.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this was to activate logs, which allowed me to see what a native query looks like.
This was done by setting the following property

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

If I understand this correctly,this parameter is set in different places, some people set it in their logging properties (remember the syntax is different)
other in their configuration.
In my case this was set in the xml configuration file that deals with the entityManager properties. Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward way to do this. Though it would be very nice for Hibernate to include a simple function of the TypedQuery of .getSql(), it requires some interesting translation. The below code works for me.

```
String hqlQueryString=typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString();
        ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
        SessionImplementor hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
        QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, hibernateSession.getFactory(), null);
        queryTranslator.compile(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
        String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```